# remove duplicate list from an arrayList using Set

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, set

I have a List that contains duplicate ArrayList.

I'm looking for a solution to remove them.

Here is an example:

```
listOne = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [3, 2], [2, 3]]
```

This set contains duplicate List. Normally i want to get :

```
theListAfterTransformation  = [[1, 0],[3, 2]]
```

Here is my tiny example, i tried to use the Set but it didn't work well.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); list1.add(1); list1.add(0);
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(); list2.add(0); list2.add(1);
        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>(); list3.add(3); list3.add(2);
        ArrayList<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>(); list4.add(2); list4.add(3);

        lists.add(list1);lists.add(list2);lists.add(list3);lists.add(list4);

        System.out.println(getUnduplicateList(lists));


    }
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getUnduplicateList( ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists) {
        Iterator iterator = lists.iterator();
        Set<ArrayList<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) iterator.next();
            set.add(list);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(set);
    }

}
```

Note that is a tiny example from my project and it will be very hard to use a solution that change many thing in this implementation.

So take into account that the getUnduplicateList should keep the same signature. the good idea will be to change only the implementation.

This program print the same list as the input. any idea please.

Comment: Made an answer with a [stream implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584733/1746118)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple notes on terminology—[`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is a distinct data structure from [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), where the former is unordered and does not allow duplicates, while the latter is a basic, linear collection, that's generally ordered, and allows duplicates. You seem to be using the terms interchangeably, which may be part of the issue you're having: `Set` is probably the appropriate data structure here.

That said, it seems that your code is relying on the `List` API, so we can follow that along. Note that you should, in general, code to the *interface* (`List`), rather than the specific class (`ArrayList`).

Additionally, consider using the [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) shorthand method for initializing a list (note that this returns an *immutable list*).

Finally, note that a `HashSet` eliminates duplicates by checking if both objects have the same [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). Lists containing the same elements are still not considered to be the same list unless the elements appear in the [same order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals--), and will typically not be treated as duplicates. Sets, however, implement [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and `hashCode` in such a way that two sets containing exactly the same elements are considered equal (order doesn't matter).

---

Using your original starting collection, you can convert each inner-list to a set. Then, eliminate duplicates from the outer collection. Finally, convert the inner-collections back to lists, to maintain compatibility with the rest of your code (if needed). This approach will work regardless of the size of the inner-lists.

You can simulate these steps using a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), and using method references to convert to and from the `Set`, as below.

---

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 0);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(0, 1);
        List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(3, 2);
        List<Integer> list4 = Arrays.asList(2, 3);

        List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3, list4);

        System.out.println(getUnduplicateList(lists));
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> getUnduplicateList(List<List<Integer>> lists) {
        return lists
                .stream()
                .map(HashSet::new)
                .distinct()
                .map(ArrayList::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you'd need to import `Arrays` and `Objects` from java.util, and import `Collectors` from java.util.stream. The javadoc for [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) goes into more detail on the `distinct`, `map`, and `collect` methods—but `distinct` eliminates duplicates, `map` converts each element to a different type, and `collect` groups the elements of the list.

Comment: whats with `a = list.get(0);
            b = list.get(1);` lines of code? can you explain what they are supposed to do, I mean the hardcoded indexes look strange.

Comment: @nullpointer It's just initializing the `Pair` with the two values from the list—it would likely benefit from some validation on the list (i.e. ensuring that input contains two and only two values), but I was trying to avoid some of the clutter. Each inner list is intended to be exactly two values, so that essentially converts `List` to `Pair`.

Comment: *Each inner list is intended to be exactly two values, so that essentially converts List to Pair* ..is worth mentioning assumption IMHO.

Comment: Plus one for the stream solution suggested :)

Comment: @nbrooks thank you for the advice, I'm reviewing my code to use the good datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the inner lists to sets as well.

Comment: yes i tried this, the problem is that i will a another solution than this. because if i use this i should review a lot of things in my project

Comment: What I meant is, you need to convert the inner lists to sets and then back to lists again, like you did with the lists that contain them already.

Comment: ok. but how to return an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> in place of Set<Set<Integer>>.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to sort your lists and then run them through `distinct` Although this is not very efficient and you will also obtain a set of sorted lists:

```
Set<List<Integer>> collect = set.stream()
            .map(list -> {
                list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
                return list;
            })
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Sorting `Integer` objects by their `int` value is the natural order, hence, you can use `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or even just `list.sort(null)`. And when you collect into a `Set`, there is no need for a preceding `distinct()`.